# Tokenizing issue with buffered reader

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

So I'm writing a java program that is supposed to keep analyzing strings from the user until the end of standard input (until they press CTRL+D or the end of an input file). The program works as intended, however when I press CTRL+D, there is a null pointer exception. Here is the code in question:

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = " ";
    while (line != null) {
        line = in.readLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(line); ......
```

The null pointer is aimed at **String[] tokens = line.split(" ");**

It looks like the code is trying to tokenize a line that is null. But I thought I wrote it in a way to never attempt to tokenize a null line. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Change your while loop to: -

```
while ((line = in.readLine())!= null) {
```

And remove the first line inside it.

Note that, you were reading the line inside the loop, and then testing later on. So, you would have got a `NPE` at the end of the file.

Also, if you are tokenizing the file after reading, I would prefer to use `Scanner` class indeed.

Comment: Thanks Rohit! I realized my error seconds after posting this haha

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `while` is a pre check condition. At the beginning of the loop, `line` isn't null. You should use a `do-while` instead.

```
while (line != null) {
    line = in.readLine(); // in the loop, but in.readLine() returns null
    String[] tokens = line.split(" "); // OH SHI- LINE IS NULL
    System.out.println(line);
```